# React Native Notification Tray and AppBar color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-paper

I am using react-native-paper along with react-navigation and the notification tray background color is not a darker shade of the AppBar color as shown in the documentations of react-native-paper and I cannot figure a way out to do that.

I have a basic project implemented and the snack of it can be seen in the following link:
https://snack.expo.dev/@throwawayacc/grumpy-milkshake

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Current Output**

[image]

As it can be seen above the notification tray color is the same as the AppBar color. How do I get it to work like the expected output. You can see the current implementation on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#backgroundcolor-android to change the status bar to a different color.

Just import the `StatusBar` from react-native. And put this code in your screens components like this. e.g.

```
// codes...

function HomeScreen(props) {
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>

      <StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor="#3B008F"
         />

      <Text>Home Screen</Text>

// codes...
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this. I tried it again and this increase the height of the AppBar. How do I get around that?

Comment: have you tried this? https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#currentheight-android

Comment: I cannot get it to work. I tried that as well. Can you maybe fork the snack and see if you can fix it?